# POWER BI the same value for a column repeated multiple times(up to 24 times), want it just once, how to fix

Tags: powerbi

I got an online campaign data, and there is an issue that the 'budget' for each day/campaign is the same but each time a campaign happens the budget repeats.
for example:

[image: the table looks like this]

I want to build a table, that shows the avg budget of each campaign for these two days, as well as the total (also avg) at the bottom, like this:

[image: the wanted table]

Comment: how do you arrive at 85 for google??

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure that calculates the Average() of the budget column.

Then create a visualisation (table or matrix) and use the campaign field along with the measure.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.